# codeigniter update returns blank page while update is done

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to run an update query with CI.

My model is:

```
function update($data)
{
    $pack = array(
        'PID'           => $data['PID'],
        'firstName'     => $data['FirstName'],
        'lastName'      => $data['LastName'],
        'BirthDate'     => $data['BirthDate'],
        'FID'           => $data['FID'],
        'BaseType'      => $data['BaseType'],
        'RaiName'       => $data['RaiName'],
        'FullAddress'   => $data['FullAddress'],
        'Company'       => $data['Company'],
        'StartDate'     => $data['StartDate'],
        'EndDate'       => $data['EndDate'],
        'Safudzveli'    => $data['Safudzveli']
    );

    $this->db->where('id',$data['Id']);
    $this->db->update('table',$pack);
}
```

After I call the model, the DB gets updated but the controller returns a blank page.
It appears that after the line in controller where I am calling the model,
nothing gets executed. (`Display_Errors` is on in php.ini so I would see any DB errors.)

Does anybody know what can be the problem?

Here is the controller:

```
public function Edit()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    if ($_POST) {
        $data = $_POST;
        $this->main->update($data);
        redirect('http://localhost/prac', 'refresh');
    }else{
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code from your controller?

Comment: i edited my post with controller code, its realy simple just to make this work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Codeigniter cleans the $_POST array so if you want that code to work you must use CI input library

try using $this->input->post()

Comment: thnx i think that was the issue

Comment: cheers!

i still wonder why would someone give my answer -1 without an explanation...

Answer (score 0):

On your data array you have data['PID']. on you where statement you have data['id']. From the code you provided I think your where statement should be like this

```
$this->db->where('id',$data['PID']);
```

Comment: nope.. that one is correct, i have input 'id' which im not using for update

Comment: You redeclare the $data array at the start of the update() method. @Rachid would be correct to assume that there is no `'Id'` in the $data array.

Comment: i just made type error for this question ill edit the code above just the way it is i ny project

Answer (score 0):

I think redirect should be like

```
redirect(site_url('controller/Method(if there)'));
die();
```